Spring Amqp Caching Connection Factory giving Consumers Canceled Channel Closed Error after migrating from rabbitmq to spring rabbitmq
We are using Spring Amqp Caching connection factory for connection to rabbitmq.We have an application which is producing messages to queue and consumers are attached to get those messages from queue.For some time it works fine but after some time we are getting  below errors for all queues.
07:45:37.736Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-h3HnCdufgSQaERjOp7m6_g identity=72d4f069]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.738Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=2, consumerTag=amq.ctag-A-Jd1zQxbTS_LP-H7A68Xg identity=38410206]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.741Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=3, consumerTag=amq.ctag-83rgbXta5kW9jz366x8UFA identity=6b1b055a]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.743Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=4, consumerTag=amq.ctag-Ggdtvr7Kt7qyo0gqdCX5rw identity=36a8d088]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.745Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=5, consumerTag=amq.ctag-_d-yhnhhznYfQSh0R8Gp1g identity=4be6bdf9]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.747Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=6, consumerTag=amq.ctag-P9o2trpAK7eJTVabagytcA identity=66c04c42]
2024-05-31 07:45:37.749Z|testapplication|test-0|[not.a.Spring.bean-consumerMonitor-1]|ERROR||||||||org.apache.camel.component.springrabbit.CamelDirectMessageListenerContainer:lambda$checkConsumers$5|578|Consumer canceled - channel closed SimpleConsumer [queue=test.queue, index=7, consumerTag=amq.ctag-tknLBHdas-GOX2rV0WOIxg identity=807b0c2]
2024-05-31 

Once the error starts coming we are unable to send messages and consumes messages from the queue.Consumers are attached to the queues but still not able to process thos e messages.
Our application is serving high number of requests and high concurrency environment.
We are using default settings of caching connection factory.
Please suggest to resolve this issue.
We have tried with CachingConnectionFactory with default settings for our application.We have migrated from rabbitmq to spring rabbitmq.
We are expecting that it should produce and consume messages.

Looks like you are using Apache Camel, which adds more variables into the picture. It might be great if you can make a simple reproducible sample, but really based on on just Spring AMQP (plus Spring Boot). I'm not good with Apache Camel to judge properly from that point of view.

Thanks for reply @ArtemBilan We are using apache camel in our environment.We have docker container environment which is connecting with cloudamqp rabbitmq.
We saw that whenever connection is dropped we are getting consumers canceled channel closed error.But still in rabbitmq all channels and consumers looks fine but no further messages are processed.
Currently we are using AcknowledgeMode as NONE and also consumer timeout is by default which is 30 mins.

Might be Firewall concern which closes those sockets

Thanks @ArtemBilan for your reply.
We have multiple concurrent consumers in our application.We are using CachingConnectionFactory with default thread pool.
We have configured concurrentConsumers in our application per queue.
In our application there are multiple queues with many consumers.
To achieve concurrency with many consumers do we need to set thread pool separately also?
If yes then how to set thread pool required for each consumer using spring amqp caching connection factory where consumers numbers can grow depending on requirement.
Please share your thoughts on this.

You would need a shared thread pool for those consumers, if the number of them is really too big and cannot be fulfilled with thread-per-consumer. The cache size must be also big enough to be aligned with the number of consumers. Each consumer takes the channel for its consume-n-delivery logic.

@ArtemBilan Thanks for the update!!
We are using CacheMode.CHANNEL which is having default value of 25.
cachingConnectionFactory.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
Using newCachedThreadPool based on documentation we found that it will create threads or reuse based on use.
Currently in our environment we have more than 4000 channels.
But after upgrading to spring amqp rabbit we need to create thread pool.
Can you please suggest how will we able to change that in order to have work properly?
Also what could be that cache size in above scenario?

You said it yourself - 4000 channels. Not sure if RabbitMQ allows that number, but if you have so many consumers, than indeed that cache has to be so big.

Thanks @ArtemBilan ..
So with camel rabbitmq, it's working in our environment; there are 4000 channels. Now, after migrating to spring rabbitmq we are using caching connection factory. In this case what would be the appropriate value for channelcachesize to cater to this many channels? Please shed some light on this.

I'm not sure. I would try make the cache for that 4000 channels.

@ArtemBilan Good day..For the above problem we found that earlier in camel -rabbitmq we used to set the thread pool based on consumers.Currently in camle spring rabbitmq we don't have that threadPool property available while creating the route.
We have set the cachingConnectionFactory.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
Using above it is able to provide threads for the consumers in order to consume and do processing on that.
Thanks for your help!!

Currently we are facing one another problem related to spring rabbitmq for producer template.Earlier while using camel rabbitmq we have used producer template which has property skipQueueDeclare=true and skipQueueBinding=true.
But in camel spring rabbitmq above properties are not present.We need alternative for this and trying to find the solution for this.We are using camel spring rabbitmq version as 4.6.0
Please share your thoughts on this.

I'm not familiar with Apache Camel, but looks like the property is autoDeclare=false: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.22.x/spring-rabbitmq-component.html#_auto_declare_exchanges_queues_and_bindings
